# NET STOP: service is not responding to the control function?

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, windows-server-2008, service

I'm trying to use a .bat script to stop two services on Windows Server 2008 (using net stop)

I get an error saying:

```
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.

Press any key to continue . . . 
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Is there any idea what is causing this and how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a batch problem, you have a problem with the service.

`NET STOP` is trying to stop the service, but the service is not responding to the request.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is the problem. But when I run net stop to the service from the command line (not from the batch), everything works fine. But when net stop is run from the batch, I get this error.

Comment: I had a similar problem with porting old code over to a newer box that didn't have multiple partitions. I was trying to write to a nonexistent log file on service stop and thus the result of the 1061 error.